# overlay seaborn stripplot over hearmap

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, scatter-plot

I have the following dataset:

```
loads_ts_comb.head()
    rte_nbr date    perc_op_capacity    is_overworked
0   35  2019-07-01  52.828054   NaN
1   35  2019-07-02  91.515837   NaN
2   35  2019-07-03  96.380090   NaN
3   35  2019-07-04  96.040724   NaN
4   35  2019-07-05  73.642534   NaN


loads_ts_comb.dtypes
rte_nbr                      int64
date                datetime64[ns]
val1                       float64
val2                       float64
```

`is_overworked` flag takes values 0/1/NaN.

Using seaborn, I want to create a heatmap for `perc_op_capacity` (with `rte_nbr` as x-axis and `date` as y-axis). Then I want to overlay a scatter plot for `is_overworked` on the heatmap (again using `rte_nbr` as x-axis and `date` as y-axis). I tried doing this:

```
## combine df
loads_ts_comb = loads_ts_comb.loc[(loads_ts_comb.date >= '2019-07-01') & (loads_ts_comb.date <= '2019-07-31')]

## get df for scatter plot
df_ts = loads_ts_comb.drop(columns='perc_op_capacity')
df_ts.sort_values(by=['rte_nbr','date'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
df_ts = df_ts.reset_index().drop(columns='index')

## get df for heatmap
df_loads = loads_ts_comb.drop(columns='is_overworked')
df_loads.sort_values(by=['rte_nbr','date'], inplace=True)
df_loads_piv = df_loads.pivot(index="date", columns="rte_nbr")
df_loads_piv.index = df_loads_piv.index.date
df_loads_piv.columns = [col[1] for col in df_loads_piv.columns.values]

## plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(df_loads_piv, ax = ax, robust=True, square=True, center=90, cmap='coolwarm',
            cbar_kws={"shrink":.3, "label": "% operating capacity"})
ax = sns.stripplot(x="rte_nbr", y="date", hue='is_overworked', palette="Set3", size=10, data=df_ts, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Percentage operating capacity by Route (x) and Date(y)', fontsize=16, fontdict={})
plt.xticks(fontsize="10")

plt.xlabel(xlabel='Route', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(ylabel='Date', fontsize=14)

#set labelsize of the colorbar
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.show()
```

I have tried out a bunch of stuff but can't get the stripplot to overlay on the heatmap. My current heatmap looks like this:

[image]

Comment: From what I have noticed, the square blocks for first and last values on x-axis get messed up when I add the stripplot line to my plotting code block. Looks weird

Comment: What do you mean by *scatter plot for `is_overworked`*?

Comment: basically, I want to overlay values for `is_overworked` flag over the heatmap using `rte_nbr` and `date` as x and y axis respectively